How to use an 8-bit parallel display with an ESP32-S3-MINI?
I've made a PCB with an ESP-32-S3-MINI connected to NHD-C12864B2Z-RN-FBW display with a built-in ST7565R controller. I've tried some libraries like U8g2 to run this display, but with no success. Pins between ESP and display on PCB are soldered correctly; I've checked them with a digital multimeter. I've also tried to write my own code to send some commands to the display, but again with no success.
Here is the wiring diagram for this display:

For the 11 capacitors I've used 1 μF and connected them like in this diagram. The rest of the pins are connected to the ESP like this:

/RD - GPIO 10
/WR - GPIO 11
/A0 - GPIO 12
/RESTB - GPIO 13
CS1B - GPIO 14
DB0 - GPIO 9
DB1 - GPIO 8
DB2 - GPIO 7
DB3 - GPIO 6
DB4 - GPIO 5
DB5 - GPIO 2
DB6 - GPIO 1
DB7 - GPIO 21

Here is the documentation:

NHD-C12864B2Z-RN-FBW
ST7565R
ESP32-S3-MINI

U8g2 has support for ST7565 (my controller is ST7565R) and it didn't worked so I've changed some commands in source code of this library, because there are some small differences in both controllers like enable level but still it is not working.
Here is my code:
#include<U8g2lib.h>

// LCD const
const int lcdRead = 10;
const int lcdWrite = 11;
const int lcdA0 = 12;
const int lcdReset = 13;
const int lcdCS = 14;
const int lcdDB[8] = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1, 21};  // DB0 to DB7

U8G2_ST7565_NHD_C12864_1_8080 u8g2(U8G2_R0, lcdDB[0], lcdDB[1], lcdDB[1], lcdDB[3], lcdDB[4], lcdDB[5], lcdDB[6], lcdDB[7], lcdWrite, lcdCS, lcdA0, lcdReset);

void setup() {
  pinMode(lcdRead, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lcdWrite, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lcdA0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lcdReset, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lcdCS, OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    pinMode(lcdDB[i], OUTPUT);
  }

  u8g2.begin();
}

void loop() {
  u8g2.firstPage();
  do {
    u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_ncenB14_tr);
    u8g2.drawStr(0,20,"Hello World!");
  } while (u8g2.nextPage());
  delay(1000);
}


How do you configure your used GPIO pin assignment in the library? Can you post the relevant code?

@Jens I've edited my question.
